# Is there a way to prevent override of php settings?

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm really tired (or lazy?) when I take back another project, to set up manually some settings like '`display_errors`', etc.

I'd like to have them set by default on my development environnement and nothing more to do to get errors showed when I first "visit" the project.

In some application it's easy and quick, but sometimes it's more than painful.

I'm pretty sure it is a PHP option to prevent the use of `ini_set` or `error_reporting` for certain settings.

Comment: Turning Safe mode on? :)

Comment: Yeah, was trying to be a bit sarcastic. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the php.ini directive `disable_functions`. It takes a comma-delimited list of function names to disable

Comment: Yep, thank you, I know about this function but I don't want to disable ini_set, I just want to prevent the override of certains options.

Answer (score 0):

There pretty much is just one option: overwrite the functions with the [runkit extension](http://php.net/runkit), proxy all calls to the original functions, unless it's setting display_errors. That should work, although it might be a bit cumbersome for such a trivial setting?

Comment: Right, it's trivial, but some projet use their own 'error setup' that's annoying when you try to debug.

Comment: True. In that case; the only viable option is overwriting the functions with runkit.